# How to assign image url programmatically in code behind?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, asp.net-4.0

I'm using file uploader to upload an image, i'm saving it in a directory and the path to that image is saved in a database. When i try to retrieve it on my web page, it does retrieve the image successfully but as i  assign that path to the url of image control in asp.net it gives an error saying File does not exist at remote server location. Any help?

```
<div id="user_pic">

          <img id="ImageMap1" src="~/App_Themes/Theme/UserPics/logo.png" />

        </div>
```

Error:

Server Error in '/WebSite2' Application.

The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.

Requested URL: /WebSite2/App_Themes/Theme/UserPics/logo.png

Comment: Can you show relevant parts of the code + debug info?

Comment: Can you verify that the image is 100% there? I'd guess something went wrong (insufficient rights or something like that). "When i try to retrieve it on my web page" - how do you retrieve it? I'd guess the filename got insterted into your database, but the actual uploading process failed and it's giving you this error, because the image wasn't actually saved.

Comment: its 100% saved in a directory i listed above!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image` control to assign the URL from the codebehind file. See [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.image.aspx).

Comment: i am having problem, when i assign Image1.ImageUrl=path; where path is the link of image in a database. it showing error which i mention above.

Answer (score 0):

Double check whether the path is saved correctly in database and make sure the image is available on the saved location.

Try adding runat = "server" to the img tag

```
<img id="ImageMap1" src="~/App_Themes/Theme/UserPics/logo.png" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing path from "~" to ".."

as:

```
<img id="ImageMap1" src="../App_Themes/Theme/UserPics/logo.png" runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

using a plain HTML img tag, you shouldn't need the prefix at all. Try changing "~/App_Themes/..." to just "App_Themes/..."